# Can I disable certificate error/warning in Firefox/Chrome/Internet Explorer?

Tags: browser, certificate, ssl-certificate

Exactly as the title says; I don't mind which browser, I just want to **type "https://........"** and see the page normally **without any certificate error**, knowing that I might risk myself by allowing an invalid certificate!

It seems like every browser producer thinks he knows better than me, the Super User !! =)

Now, does anyone know how to remove warning/error related to this? In any of these browsers (Firefox/Chrome/Internet Explorer/[you-may-suggest])?

Oh, and don't advise me a workaround like adding to exceptions. Please don't mention that.
I'd highly appriciate a concise & precise answer!

Edit:
The answer I seek concerns ONLY the browser. No third-party objects to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some proxies have this "feature".

Your https requests are terminated by the proxy and resent to the remote server. As long as you have imported the proxy's certificate into your browser's store, you won't ever see a certificate error because as far as your browser is concerned, no problem exists.

Comment: Have I not with less than 125 rep. points I'd -1 this answer for advising me to add an exception, just in a bit different words. Thanks though for at least trying to figure an answer for that!

Answer (score 0):

(for firefox) after reading this i figured "update or reinstall", have a look and tell me what you think http://support.mozilla.com/hi-IN/questions/747313 i assume this to be the same as your problem, hope it helps

Comment: Hi - thanks although that isn't my issue, or related, as far as I understand. These guys talk about a valid certificate which works on IE but not on FF, while I'm talking about a certificate which isn't backed up by any CA, it's a self-signed one, yet I cannot add it to exceptions.

Comment: hmmm... have you tried stabbing it?