# How to accept a HTTPS server's invalid certificate in a given client machine?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, https, ssl-certificate

A HTTPS server I'm browsing uses an invalid certificate. I want my machine to ignore this error and think that the certificate is valid. How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I disable certificate error/warning in Firefox/Chrome/Internet Explorer?](http://superuser.com/questions/213539/can-i-disable-certificate-error-warning-in-firefox-chrome-internet-explorer)

Comment: Disabling certificates is not a solution. You're leaving yourself open to expired certificates, an attacker trying to intercept communications and/or tampering with your internet connection. It is better to accept the invalid certificate only if you know and trust as to why this is happening.

Comment: @kobaltz I don't want to disable all certificate checking, just this one

Comment: correct, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on each browser. Your server has a certificate, but each browser will display that this certificate was generated by an unknown authority.

Personally, I run a private cloud which is accessible only within my network. I know that it communicates with a secure connection and that the certificate was self generated by the server. Knowing this, I know that my connection is still encrypted but is not authorized/verified with a known agent. I will always get these errors.

**However, it is not a good idea to disable the error/warning as that is no different than removing your Check Engine light bulb. Hides the problem but does not solve your root issue.**

Firefox:
[image]

This part will allow you to add the exception for the certificate and not display this information again while keeping the connection secured.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I know this, I don't want to simply avoid this message. I want the machine to trust the invalid certificate.

Comment: If you use Firefox, it will install the certificate as described above.

Comment: What about in Firefox 51?  I don't see the "I understand the Risks" link any more.  I've searched the world over for a way to add an exception.